# Should I place the Subdivision modifier higher in the stack than the solidify modifier for the best geometry for 3D printing?

Tags: modifiers, subdivision-surface, 3d-printing, solidify-modifier

When creating a model in Blender that is intended to be 3D printed, what is the most effective order to place a subdivision surface modifier and a solidify modifier in the stack in terms of giving cleanest geometry and the least distortion or poke through

Comment: The quality of the model is determined by the quality of the base mesh, not modifiers. The order of modifiers is a modeling decision, it affects the shape of the result, not its "quality". Without so much as a screenshot of your objective we can't possibly guess what you are asking about

Comment: The question was very specific, the desired outcome is a clean set of geometry to base a 3D print on. Supplying a screen shot would introduce subjective elements based on the mesh used. What is being sought is an objective answer based on best practice when creating models for 3D printing using Blender. I don't want an opinion on which mesh looks better, I want to know which will produce the optimal mesh with the least distortions.